# Can you remote debug a shared object in Eclipse when you don't have the source code of the executeble?

Tags: c

I'm trying to debug a shared library I wrote in C. This .so is loaded by an executable. My question is: can I debug my shared library remotely via gdb if I have no access to the source code of the executable?

I figured out how to debug the .so from the executable project and everything works fine. For the future of the project it would be awesome to debug from the shared library project without accesses to the source code of the executable.

My target is a BeagleBone Black with Debian 9.5., my IDE is Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0) which runs on Ubuntu with CDT.

I start the executable with the Eclipse debugger setting "Commands to execute before application"

The executable runs fine, but I can not insert breakpoints. I get the following error

> "Breakpoint installation failed: cannot access memory at address 0x20f4"